# Why can't I read this registry key in C#

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry

Problem

- I cannot read from the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-436374069-1965331169-839522115-50811\AnyoneRead\LockScreen.`

Using Code:

```
Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-436374069-1965331169-839522115-50811\AnyoneRead\LockScreen", "", null);
```

Diagnostics of problem

- I get a System.NullReferenceException when executing code like the key does not exits, but I know it exist because I can view it in regedit.
- I have tried to take ownership of the key.
- I have tried viewing subkeys of parent key (CurrentVersion). The parent scan never even showed the key SystemProtectedUserData key same with the key right under TabletPC.

I am guessing this is some permission problem but I dont know how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`Registry.GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8) method returns `null`, because it can't find a specified key or value and the default value (the third argument) is set to `null`. According to documentation, this method can't throw a `NullReferenceException`, it seems the consuming code causes it.

So, you can try to specify the value name (at my end I see only `OSVersion` value) or different default value.

If the issue still exist, the problem can be in redirection to `WOW6432Node` registry node in x64 edition of Windows. You can avoid it by the following code, using [`OpenBaseKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8) method and specifying a [`RegistryView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8) value

```cs
var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
var key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-...\AnyoneRead\LockScreen");
var value = key.GetValue("OSVersion"); //for example
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the `valueName` thus it returns the default value, which you set to null.

[Check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8). (More specifically, you defined it to `string.Empty` which is not a valid name. Maybe *LockScreen* is the name of the value/registry-variable? - I don't speak android)